# Is there a range version of IsNumeric just like VBA function HasFormula?

Tags: vba, excel

I know that `range().HasFormula`returns True only when every cell in the range has formula, otherwise it can return False or Null (when mixed). But there's no function like HasNumber. So to check if a range only contains number, I have to do

```
Dim all_numeric As Boolean
all_numeric = True
For Each cell In Range()
    If (Not IsNumeric(cell)) Or IsEmpty(cell) Then 'I also want to get rid of empty cell
        all_numeric = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Besides, there's `WorksheetFunction.IsNumber` that does similar thing but still needs a loop through the range. *I am not sure if this can be very slow if the range contains a lot of numbers.* And I wonder if there's any better way to check numeric values over a range object in VBA.

Comment: Maybe `all_numeric = (r.Cells.Count - Application.Count(r)) = 0` (where `r` is a `Range` object)?

Comment: @YowE3K Well, beautiful!

Comment: This would be what [codereview.se] does best. I'd actually include the function's signature / entire body though; if it's just a part of a bigger procedure, I'd include that whole procedure. If that procedure uses module-level variables, I'd just include the whole module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Maybe `all_numeric = (r.Cells.Count - Application.Count(r)) = 0` (where `r` is a `Range` object)? – [YowE3K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535336/yowe3k) [35 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566582/is-there-a-range-version-of-isnumeric-just-like-vba-function-hasformula#comment74183608_43566582)

That's indeed [beautiful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566582/is-there-a-range-version-of-isnumeric-just-like-vba-function-hasformula#comment74183715_43566582): it leverages Excel's own *function that returns the number of numeric values in a range* to determine the result:

> **WorksheetFunction.Count**
>
> Counts the number of cells that contain numbers and counts numbers within the list of arguments.
>
> <sub>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840324.aspx</sub>

Error cells and empty cells aren't counted, which fulfills your requirement of not counting empty cells.

That makes a nice UDF to expose in a standard module I find:

```
'@Description("Returns True if all cells in specified range have a numeric value.")
Public Function IsAllNumeric(ByVal target As Range) As Boolean
    IsAllNumeric = target.Cells.Count - Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(target) = 0
End Function
```

---

Note that I've used `Application.WorksheetFunction.Count`, not `Application.Count`:

- The latter is a late-bound call that makes the VBA runtime work much harder than it needs to, to find the `Count` method. You're working on an *extended COM interface*, so you don't have compile-time validation either: `Application.IDontExist` compiles perfectly fine, and blows up with run-time error 438. As with any other late-bound member call, the VBE's *IntelliSense* can't help you with the parameters:

  [image: no intellisense]
- The former is an *early-bound* function call, which VBA resolves at compile-time. You're working on the `WorksheetFunction` interface directly, so the VBE gives you *autocomplete* and *IntelliSense* for the parameters.

  Autocomplete:

  [image: autocomplete]

  IntelliSense:

  [image: intellisense]

The fact that the call is early-bound means no run-time overhead, therefore better performance - even if it ends up being the exact same internal Excel function that executes.

The drawback (if it's one at all) is that the late-bound `Application.SomeFunction` stuff is compatible with Excel4Macros, the old legacy pre-VBA way of automating Excel. So instead of *raising* run-time errors like their early-bound counterparts, the late-bound functions *return* error *values* such that you <s>can</s> *should* test them with `IsError` before you can assume what type you're actually getting.

With an early-bound `WorksheetFunction.SomeFunction` call, if the result Excel would display is `#REF!` or `#VALUE!`, or `#N/A` or whatever other possible error value, then you'll never be caught with a *type mismatch* run-time error for treating an error value as a `String` or a `Long`, or any other non-error VBA type. Instead, you just handle run-time errors, as you would with any other VBA API function call.

The late-bound call propagates an error value into your code; the early-bound call *fails early*: there could be 20 lines of code between where a cell value is read and where that value is used in a way that assumes there's no error value, and *that instruction* throws a *type mismatch* - and then you need to debug to trace back to the function that *returned* an error. With the early-bound code the function itself throws the error, so you don't have to dig it up.

Comment: @ This is an overqualified answer, thanks. Two trivial questions, 1. `Application.WorksheetFunction.Count` is the same as `WorksheetFunction.Count`? 2. You used `IsAllNumeric(ByVal target As Range)` not `IsAllNumeric(target As Range)` (the default reference version), is this just a personal habbit?

Comment: Yep, `WorksheetFunction.Count` is the same as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Count` ...I just like overqualifying stuff ;-)  as for ByVal, I hold a bit of a grudge on VBA/VB6 for making the default ByRef (VB.NET fixed that). If the pointer doesn't need to be modified by the function, then the function shouldn't be given that ability. Accidents happen so fast! Yes, there's a bit of "copy the pointer" overhead. But if *that* is your performance bottleneck then you've *already* over-optimized.